# Is my understanding about Balanced Field correct?

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff, v-speeds, rejected-takeoff

We have two definitions:

- Balanced Field where Takeoff Distance Required = Accelerated Stop Distance Required
- Balanced V1 = This is the speed where on a balanced field length (TODR=ASDR) if we have an engine failure slightly below V1 (Specifically at Vef) we will cover the same amount of distance if we decide to go and reach the screen height of 35 ft or to stop the aircraft at the end of the runway.

Is that correct?

Comment: Related: [Is "balanced field" defined with or without an engine failure?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77431/is-balanced-field-defined-with-or-without-an-engine-failure)

Comment: Related: [What happens if an engine fails between V1 and V2?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/11598/19)